# Resample layer but keep RGB bands (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, resampling, rgb

I have an orthophoto from a drone with a spatial resolution of 0.02m and would like to reduce the resolution to 1m. The simplest way of doing this is using the export>save as>and manually fill in a resolution of 1m. But I would like to do this resolution reduction several times (0.3m, 0.1m, 1m etc.). In this case I think its best to use the resampling function and run it as a batch process, but the resulting layer of a resampling process does not contain the RGB bands.

So the question is: how do I perform a resolution reduction without messing up the RGB bands. Additionally I would like to know if there is a difference between the resampling function and resampling when performing an export.

Comment: Sorry, which tool do you use for resampling?

Comment: r.resample from the GRASS toolbox

Comment: It would not be very complicated to run gdal_translate a few times with different `-tr` values https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html. Or use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html which offers more resampling methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use raster calculator in batch mode (individually for each band) and then merge the bands together. For several resolutions at once, creting a model would be an option.